# How to deal with edittext implimented dynamically with same id that replicates same data?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

What I want to achieve here is that When the activity is opened ,there is an `EditText` and when I type something into it ,another copy of same layout is produced below it until I dont want anymore lists to add.

I tried to achieve it by implementing `RecyclerView` and on each click on `EditText` I added textchangedlistener to increase the size of Arraylist which inturn adds a layout in `recyclerview`.
I also inserted data into the Arraylist on `onCreate` method ,to let recyclerview display the first `EditText`

The implementation of onclick method is given below

```
        public void onClick(String edittext_string, final EditText editText, CheckBox checkBox, final list_adapter list_adapter, final View view, final list_adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.edit_text_list) {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
          @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (position[viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()] != null && position[viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()] == 1)
                    checklist = 1;
                else {
                    checklist = 0;
                }
                if (!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) 
                    if (checklist == 0) {
                        list_text = editText.getText().toString();
                        list_entry_model_list.add(new List_Entry_Model(list_text));
                        if (viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() >= 0)
                            position[viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()] = 1;    
                    }

            }
```

The error I get is that the same data is replicated in all the `EditTexts` .In the next dynamic layout ,the text entered in previous `EditText`is reflected. I know this is an implementation error.
 I want to know if this is the correct way of achieving it ?  and Any alternatives to achieve this?

How can I add the text of the same `edittext` to itself ,without setting it to next Layout?

**onCreateViewHolder code**

```
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview_checkbox, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
```

Iam still learning and . I will provide extra code if needed.Thank You.(This is a notes app to add list notes)

Comment: How many times is onClick called? because addTextChangeListener can be called multiple times, and so it will be executed multiple times

Comment: please show your onCreateViewHolder

Comment: I have  set some conditions so that  on each editText click ,the code is executed only once . OncreateViewHolder code is provided above @LenaBru